# Nodejs mongodb native driver, execution order of async requests

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Does anyone have a nice way of ordering mongodb requests since Nodejs is async.

Say that I insert data1 into the database, and I immediately request to read that data, my read request might get executed before the data is written to the database.

Is there a nice way around this instead of forcing synchronous behavior on the requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple use callback that will be called only after insert will be completed.

```
var
    mongodb = require('mongodb'),
    client = new mongodb.Db('test', new mongodb.Server('127.0.0.1', 27017, {})),
    test = function (err, collection) {
        collection.insert({ hello : 'world' }, {safe:true}, function(err, docs) {
            collection.count(function(err, count) {
                console.log(count);
            });

            collection.find({ hello : 'world' }).toArray(function(err, results) {
                console.log(results);
            });
        });
    };

client.open(function(err, client) {
    client.collection('test_collection', test);
});
```

If you need more complex functionality look at [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module. It should help you to organize many callbacks.